# Indesign - scriping xlink:href via scripts

Tags: adobe-indesign, xml

I have xml in the following format:

```
   <WebsiteAsHyperLink><websitewithURL xlink:href="http://www.google.com"> Click to view website </websitewithURL></WebsiteAsHyperLink>
```

and I have the following script, when ran it converts `hrefs` into valid tags, but it does not work on `xlinks`

If I could get some help on how to alter it to look at all `xlinks`

```
main();

function main() {
   var doc = app.activeDocument;
   var elems = doc.xmlElements;
   var ruleSet = new Array (new Rule);
   __processRuleSet(elems[0], ruleSet);

   function Rule() {
      this.name = "Rule";
      this.xpath = "//websitewithURL [@href]";
      this.apply = function(elem, ruleProcessor) {
         var elemText = elem.texts[0];
         var linkURL = elem.xmlAttributes.itemByName("href").value;
         var linkSource = doc.hyperlinkTextSources.add(elemText);
         var linkDest = doc.hyperlinkURLDestinations.add(linkURL);
         doc.hyperlinks.add(linkSource, linkDest);
         return true;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

XPath implementation in ExtendScript is far from complete. A lot of things and function that would work in a fully compliant XPath environment will fail.

Here is another approach that seems to do the work:

```
main();
function main() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var root = doc.xmlElements[0];
    var urls = root.evaluateXPathExpression ( "//websitewithURL[@*]" ), nUrl;
    var n = urls.length, xAttr, text;
    while ( n-- ) {
       nUrl = urls[n];
       xAttr = nUrl.xmlAttributes.item ( "xlink:href" );
       if ( xAttr.isValid ) {
            var linkSource = doc.hyperlinkTextSources.add(nUrl.xmlContent);
             var linkDest = doc.hyperlinkURLDestinations.add(xAttr.value);
             doc.hyperlinks.add(linkSource, linkDest);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.xpath = "//websitewithURL [@xlink:href]"
```

Comment: I've tried that, throws an exception